# I made a code with Biopython but it does not work every time. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, sequence, extract, biopython, fasta

I have a FASTA file which contains sequences classified in an order from 1 (the first sequence: from `>` to `*`) to n (the last). The content is as follows:

```
 >TRINITY_GG_10000_c0_g1_i1.p2 TRINITY_GG_10000_c0_g1~~TRINITY_GG_10000_c0_g1_i1.p2  ORF type:complete len:381 (+),score=55.64 TRINITY_GG_10000_c0_g1_i1:244-1386(+)
MNSFLSIRKRTSLATASKTRQLNWKPAKVSIRVTSNDKKLPVTQADVARKETSKHVSMLE
TTPKLKKSFIFMAGRVVRVMIGSFLVLFALLHMGILHTLSPAVKKGLGNFSSRTWQAAEQ
IFTGKWEDHEATATAFEHGF*
>TRINITY_GG_10000_c0_g1_i1.p1 TRINITY_GG_10000_c0_g1~~TRINITY_GG_10000_c0_g1_i1.p1  ORF type:5prime_partial len:1567 (-),score=319.89 TRINITY_GG_10000_c0_g1_i1:1694-6394(-)
SPNAVQQVPVQSPNAVQQVPVQSPNAVQQVPVQSARAIQQVPNQNPNAVQQWTRHPGAMQ
QPVQDSRAIQQQQQNNSSVQAQPQATGHHARQVDESTTRSGPEVPVSSQQGHTNAPSDV*
>TRINITY_GG_10000_c0_g1_i1.p........
```

And I have another text file containing numbers corresponding to some sequence classification in the first FASTA file, the content is like this:

```
10140
10178
11626
12110
12119
n
```

I tried to create a program that allows me to extract the sequences from the FASTA file that correspond to the number contained in the text file, my program doesn't work well. The extracted sequences do not correspond to the number of sequences desired and numbered in the text file. What is wrong with my program?

```
import sys
fasta_name = sys.argv[1]
nums_name = sys.argv[2]
out_name = sys.argv[3]

from Bio import SeqIO

fasta_sequences = list(SeqIO.parse(fasta_name, "fasta"))


nums_file = open(nums_name,"r")
nums=nums_file.readlines()
nums_file.close()

out_file = open(out_name,"w")
out_file.close()
out_file = open(out_name,"a+")

numsAsInt= [int(num[:-1]) for num in nums]
indexes = set(range(1,len(fasta_sequences)+1)).intersection(set(numsAsInt))

for ind in indexes:
        fasta = fasta_sequences[ind-1]
        name, sequence = fasta.id, str(fasta.seq)
        out_file.write(">"+name+"\n")
        out_file.write(sequence+"\n")

out_file.close()
```

I have tried to solve this problem but being a beginner with Python I can't go further. What can I try next?

Comment: How is it wrong? What have you done to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I hope you still need an answer:

The problem faulty list I provided my answer as code I tested it and it works.

I also provided a alternative more biopythonic way to do it:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
fasta_name = 'test.fasta'
nums_name = 'test.list'
out_name = 'out2.fasta'

from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Seq

fasta_sequences = list(SeqIO.parse(fasta_name, "fasta"))
#print the number of sequences in the file

"""
nums_file = open(nums_name,"r") # 
nums=nums_file.readlines()
nums_file.close()
#produced: ['1 \ n', '3 \ n', '4'] these are strings not ints
    ['1\ n', '3\ n', '4'] needs to be [1,3,4] fix file readlines

"""

#nicer way to read in the list of numbers
nums=[]
with open(nums_name, 'r') as f:
    nums_raw=f.readlines()
    #strip newlines if they exist
    nums=[x.strip() for x in nums_raw]
    #turn nums into integers
    nums=[int(x) for x in nums]
    

out_file = open(out_name,"w")
out_file.close()
out_file = open(out_name,"a+")

#numsAsInt= [int(num[:-1]) for num in nums] 
# caused an error and is now no longer needed since we already have ints
numsAsInt=nums
indexes = set(range(1,len(fasta_sequences)+1)).intersection(set(numsAsInt))

#you can directly iterate over the SeqIO object and provide the indexes as a list
for ind in nums:
        fasta = fasta_sequences[ind-1] #generally it would be advisable to start indexes from 0
        name, sequence = fasta.id, str(fasta.seq)
        out_file.write(">"+name+"\n")
        out_file.write(sequence+"\n")

out_file.close()

# a more  biopython way is this:
fasta_sequences = list(SeqIO.parse(fasta_name, "fasta"))
nums=[]
with open(nums_name, "r") as f:
    nums=[int(x.strip()) for x in f.readlines()]
selected_seqs = [fasta_sequences[ind-1] for ind in nums]
SeqIO.write(selected_seqs, out_name, "fasta")
```

The last one is the shortest and efficient way to do it.

[tag]